# How to change the media volume instead of ringtone volume by pressing the HW volume buttons

Tags: android, audio, volume

I want to increase the media volume instead of ringtone volume, if user press volume button when application is running on the device. working on android java

Comment: You could at least post some code you have already.

Comment: I got it setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); actually i was searching for a code that set media volume bedefault in my application. now Its working fine.

Comment: @Michael Thanks. Now I come to know. I will carry In my mind Next time about How to post Questions.